# Spending, expense, spend or what?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing a simple finance app and I would like to know what is the best way of saying that a new expense is to be added (e.g. I bought a coffee and I want to register that event). The following are the phrases that I've either come up with myself, or that someone proposed to me:

- Add Spending
- Add Expense
- Add Spend (this was actually proposed by a professional translator, but it feels wrong)

Which one is correct, and are there any better alternatives? My requirement is that it should not be too formal, but rather some kind of everyday language that can be understood by both native and non-native english speakers.

Comment: I'll go for the second one as I find it most intuitive of the three.

Comment: "Spend" as a noun is terrible business jargon that I have only been aware of for a year or two.  I find it truly offensive.  You will alienate some users if you pick that option.

Comment: @phoog I agree, that's why I'm amazed that this option was proposed by a professional translator...

Comment: Perhaps the professional translator's concentration is in business, and/or his clients are fond of jargon.

Comment: That's likely the case, however, when I ask for a translator for an App Store text, and explicitly point out that the text should be as generic as possible, then I expect that a professional translator manages to do that... Well, anyway, thanks for your input! That helped me out together with input from some english-native friends of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the 2nd one suits right ie. Add expense. As you're making an app so usage of phrases instead of sentences would be better otherwise "Add this expense" would sound much conventional
.